# drupal preview not working - previewing node edit displays previous saved node instead

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Preview only works for new nodes before saving, but after I saved the node, edit and click preview:

**Preview trimmed & Preview full version** both show the last saved state instead.

Any advise how I can check what might prevent it or whether it's set up correctly?

**FYI** /modules/node/node.pages.inc:

```
function theme_node_preview($variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  $output = '<div class="preview">';

  $preview_trimmed_version = FALSE;

  $elements = node_view(clone $node, 'teaser');
  $trimmed = drupal_render($elements);
  $elements = node_view($node, 'full');
  $full = drupal_render($elements);
```

...

```
$enter code hereform['actions']['preview'] = array(
        '#access' => variable_get('node_preview_' . $node->type, DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_DISABLED,
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Preview'),
        '#weight' => 10,
        '#submit' => array('node_form_build_preview'),
```

Comment: Anybody experienced this or can give help how to check this please?

Comment: Seems like it's working now, I have caching disabled, could this interfere?